# How to stub a method defined with method_missing in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Assume I have some properly structured meta code like

```
class Administrator < ParseInterface
  attr_accessor :args, :new_student
  include GeneralHelper

  def initialize args = {}
    @args = args
    @new_student = build_student
  end

end

class ParseInterface
  PARSE_METHOD_PREFIX = /\A(parse_){1}/

  def self.method_missing method_name, args = nil
    parse_method?(method_name) ? call_parse(method_name, args) : super
  end

  def self.parse_method? method_name
    method_name.to_s.match(PARSE_METHOD_PREFIX) ? true : false
  end

  def self.to_parse method_name
    (remove_parse_prefix(method_name)).camelize(:lower)
  end

  def self.remove_parse_prefix method_name
    method_name.to_s.gsub(PARSE_METHOD_PREFIX, "")
  end

  def self.call_parse method_name, args
    set_session_token args
    begin
      Parse::Cloud::Function.new(to_parse(method_name)).call(args)
    rescue Exception => e
      NewRelic::Agent.agent.error_collector.notice_error(e)
    end
  end

end
```

I have the ability to call things like `Administrator.parse_do_stuff` and the parse interface class will notice the `parse` prefix and then make a subsequent call to the parse api.  I'd like to stub some of these dynamically generated methods and in particular, I'd like to be able to

```
allow(Administrator).to receive(:parse_rooms_for_user).and_return([{objectId: @room.parse_pointer }])
```

but rspec is throwing a not implemented error.  I've looked at quite a good blog post, http://blog.enriquez.me/2010/2/21/dont-forget-about-respond-to-when-implementing-method-missing/ that seems to be approaching this but I'm unclear on a solution.  Ergo, how to stub a dynamically generated class method in ruby?

Thx,

JD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question with the link to http://blog.enriquez.me/2010/2/21/dont-forget-about-respond-to-when-implementing-method-missing/. You need to add a `respond_to_missing?` method that accurately returns whether or not either your method_missing or the object will respond to a certain call. In short, add this method:

```
def self.respond_to_missing?(method, private = false)
  parse_method?(method)
end
```

EDIT: Changed to use `respond_to_missing?` instead of `respond_to?`, see [Jörg W Mittag's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32513515/how-to-stub-a-method-defined-with-method-missing-in-ruby/32513792?noredirect=1#comment52887321_32513792)

Comment: That scenario is exactly what `respond_to_missing?` was added to support.